# nil localizedTitle in SKProduct

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm implementing an in-app store and am successfully getting SKProducts from the app store. The price information and description in the SKProducts are fine, but all my localizedTitles are nil. In iTunes Connect, the reference name is set, and I added an English language and set the Display Name and Description. Any idea why localizedTitles is coming back as nil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same issue here, check https://devforums.apple.com/message/681255 - you are not alone. It's something at the Apple side.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead. I tried editing and resaving the title and description and to something different but I'm only getting the price information. EDIT: I realized I also had a "Subscription Group", I edited the title of it and saved, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

**Roll back your version number in Xcode.**

For example, in my situation, I had `MARKETING_VERSION=1.23` in Xcode. I had submitted this on App Store Connect as version 1.23. Apple then **rejected** version 1.23 in review. After this rejection, `SKProductsRequest` continued to serve a list of `SKProduct`s, but each product's `.localizedTitle` and `.localizedDescription` were set to `nil`.

In Xcode, I changed my version number (i.e. `MARKETING_VERSION`) back to 1.22. After this, the `.localizedTitle` and `.localizedDescription` were served correctly again.

Temporarily changing the version number is a workaround for testing and development prior to resubmitting your app for review.

This is surely a bug on Apple's side. [I have submitted a bug report here](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/8997618), but it seems like I can't get a public link to the report.

Comment: This worked for me... incremented my build number by 1, new IAPs from App Store Connect are now sending along the localized name and description.  I tried decrementing it back to the original build number and the name and description failed to send.  Incrementing the build number back up by 1 fixed it ‍♂️.

Answer (score 0):

Apple seem to have broken this at some point between the 20th of June and the 21st for both iOS and Mac app stores (both live and sandbox). Unfortunately if you are trusting in a valid response your app will crash.

For anyone with a live app if you don't require a persistant internet connection a short term work around for some users can be to enable airport mode on iOS, not sure if "turn off your internet connection" is much help to anyone experiencing this on the Mac app store.