# iTunesConnect returns 'nil' as localizedTitle for SKProduct

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, null, skproduct

I have some In App Products in my application to buy. Yesterday things were fine but today i have some troubles. I receive list of all my products but `localizedTitle` and `localizedDescription` are `nil` (while `price` and `priceLocale` are OK). 
I know that something like this happened before and it was Apple's fault. [nil localizedTitle in SKProduct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134303/nil-localizedtitle-in-skproduct)

However today I've got message from Apple about all of my In-App Purchases: "In-App Purchases have been returned and are highlighted in the table below". All of them still have status:Waiting For Review.

And now I'm wondering if getting `nil` from `localizedTitle` is connected with some Apple's bug or maybe it's my fault and I can do something with this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've found solution at *devforums.apple.com*

> https://devforums.apple.com/message/966757#966757

Basically it appeared that each product language had status **rejected** (while product had status **waiting for review**). Adding new language to each product solves problem.

Comment: Or even editing the current language's description, like adding a space or so.

Comment: This link seems to be dead. Anyone have a working one?

Answer (score 1):

**Roll back your version number in Xcode.**

For example, in my situation, I had `MARKETING_VERSION=1.23` in Xcode. I had submitted this on App Store Connect as version 1.23. Apple then **rejected** version 1.23 in review. After this rejection, `SKProductsRequest` continued to serve a list of `SKProduct`s, but each product's `.localizedTitle` and `.localizedDescription` were set to `nil`.

In Xcode, I changed my version number (i.e. `MARKETING_VERSION`) back to 1.22. After this, the `.localizedTitle` and `.localizedDescription` were served correctly again.

Temporarily changing the version number is a workaround for testing and development prior to resubmitting your app for review.

This is surely a bug on Apple's side. [I have submitted a bug report here](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/8997618), but it seems like I can't get a public link to the report.